# Can I configure Unattended Upgrades to not upgrade packages that require a reboot?

Tags: upgrade

I want to have automatic upgrades enabled, but not have my machines automatically reboot. I'd rather install those packages as part of a maintenance regiment that would also reboot the machines.

Right now we run automatic upgrades, but the machines keep reporting a need to be rebooted.

Any guide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with pinning packages to prevent them from upgrading is that to upgrade them you need to unpin them again.

The file `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs` contains a list of packages that trigger the request for a reboot after unattended-upgrade has run.

Inside the configuration file for unattended-upgrades in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` there is a section dedicated to preventing some packages from being upgraded automatically that looks like this

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist{
    foo_package1;
    foo_package2;
    foo_package3;
}
```

Edit the list to prevent those packages from being upgraded automatically.

I would start by blacklisting the usual suspects: kernel, libc, gcc, etc and every time you see the computer is asking for a reboot check `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs` and add those packages to the unattended upgrades blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

I've only seen this happen when I update the kernel. If you can identify which packages cause a need to reboot, you can put these packages on hold. This will prevent them from being updated automatically or by a regular update command.

There is information about holding packages in the Ubuntu Documentation. Look at this page:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Introduction_to_Holding_Packages