# Unattended upgrades on ubuntu server - how to avoid restarting services

Tags: apt, server, 20.04, 22.04, unattended-upgrades

I want to keep a server up to date, but also not force a restart of things like docker or all of systemd, which would affect running containers of a running system.

What software would be good to put on ignore for this, and do manually/scripted when needed.

I'm thinking:

- docker
- systemd
- HA software like corosync/pacemaker

What else could be on here?

Relevant to Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Unattended Upgrades restarts anything in the default configuration. It updates software on disk but the new versions won't be applied until you restart the relevant running software by yourself (whether manually or according to your own automations/scripts).

U-U can be configured to automatically reboot the entire system after upgrading, but I don't think it can do restarts for individual services. (That will require U-U to know about individual service configs, something that will make the tool too complicated.)

Will be glad to be corrected if I'm mistaken.

Comment: It's a fairly complex python script, from the looks of it. On first glance I can't quite make out which steps does the actual upgrade. That being said, if I `apt-get upgrade` and docker containers are running, I can see those get restarted, which is bad in a production environment.

Comment: Regardless of the python script's details, here's an old issue by a maintainer explaining that services do indeed get restarted: https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/issues/284

Comment: @KdgDev Ah, I see. I also found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/841491/1739367) which explains that it's the particular package which determines if it gets restarted upon upgrade, so I guess you really won't find the restart logic in the U-U script itself. Anyway, to try to answer your question, if your prod services run on Docker behind an HA proxy, it seems like your list already covers everything. Maybe you can do an `htop` and see what other services run on your server that you may want to exempt from upgrades?

Comment: Indeed, and go over the output of `dpkg --list` to be complete. The real issue is knowing for sure which services are affected. A real nice thing would be to know if the upgrade of any individual package, causes a service restart for some reason that's not immediately apparent on the surface